# How to do updates without going live using shopify

Tags: shopify

Hey Guys I'm new to shopify,
My use case is 
I want to do changes in existing shopify theme and want to show my client without going live

is there any way to do it
Something like - Duplicating that theme and put it to /demo - something like this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Yes you can duplicate a theme, edit it, and then give your client a "preview" link -- all without setting up a Partner account or a dev shop.**

The process is this:

- Duplicate the current theme
- Rename and edit the new theme -- this will not affect the live shop
- Preview the new theme and copy/paste the preview link and send it to the client (it will work without the client needing to log in to the shop admin)

Here's a screenshot from a shop I administer:

[image: Shopify theme edit & preview]

Answer (score -1):

I generally get the downloaded theme from the client and install it in my dev shop. 
You install it by uploading a .zip file your client exports from his current theme.

This creates a new theme in your dev shop. You can preview that theme or publish it when you are ready to show your client.

You do most of your work in your dev shop.

When you are ready to validate your work on the client's shop you export the theme you've been working on and the client uploads it to their shop. This creates a new theme. The client can preview the theme and suggest edits/fixes. This can go on until the client is happy with the theme.

Then they can publish the theme so it goes live. Very sane and much less stress than some systems I've developed for.

Answer (score -1):

I just did a project where I had to redo an existing client site and used a dev store. First of all, you have to have to Shopify Partner account. Sign up here: https://www.shopify.com/partners

As a Shopify Partner, you can create dev stores.

https://docs.shopify.com/partners/getting-started/development-stores

Once you are a Shopify Partner, you can log in to your partner dashboard and create new development stores.

First, I exported my client's current theme on the live site and installed it into the dev store.

Then, I imported her products as I was changing collections and product tags and needed to ensure products were showing up in the right places.

If you need to import products from the live site to your dev store for testing, go to Products and then click Export. first export them into a plain CSV file, and then import that CSV into your dev store by going to Product and clicking Import. (Note: if you open up the spreadsheet into Excel etc. before importing it won't work. Also there is a limit to how many products you can import in one CSV file - I think it is 999. After that you have to break them up into multiple CSV files.)

In terms of pages and collections, if you need to create new ones, you will need to create them in the dev store and then recreate them in the live store by hand. There appears to be no automated way to export collections. You can add a site password in Settings on the live site while doing the migration.

Hope that helps!

Comment: If you are simply doing theme changes, @Ben Dunlap's answer works well. If you need to redo your site at the level of not just theme, but pages and collections/products, try my method. :-)